# Can not find codec for 'png' image format

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings, I'm trying to install gazebo and ROS at my Ubuntu 11.10, But I'm getting some errors after I try to run roslaunch **gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch** , this is what I get:

---

gazebo: /home/k/Programs/ogre_src_v1-7-4/OgreMain/include/OgreSingleton.h:80: Ogre::Singleton::Singleton() [with T = Ogre::TerrainPageSourceListenerManager]: Assertion `!ms_Singleton' failed.
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 13366, exit code -6].
log files: /home/k/.ros/log/87ad5d8a-600e-11e1-ab32-0024d690acd8/gazebo-2*.log

---

The above mentioned log does not exist in the given folder.  :(

So I tried running gzserver and then gzclient, which rendered:

---

k@k-Inspiron-1545:~$ gzclient
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.0.0-RC2
Copyright (C) 2011 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Ogre::ItemIdentityException'
what():  OGRE EXCEPTION(5:ItemIdentityException): Can not find codec for 'png' image format.
There are no formats supported (no codecs registered). in Codec::getCodec at /build/buildd/ogre-1.7.3/OgreMain/src/OgreCodec.cpp (line 69)
Aborted
k@k-Inspiron-1545:~$

---

But freeimage has been installed, shouldn't it be working?

Thanks in advance!

K

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28526/can-not-find-codec-for-%27png%27-image-format./) by [Kirus](https://answers.ros.org/users/1814/kirus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a gazebo issue.  I suggest you ask on http://answers.gazebosim.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0